# How to get user input indefinitely into a C# list

Tags: c#, .net

I'm quite new to programming, and currently learning C#. I was trying to build a contacts app that accepts name and phone number from users and stores them into a C# loop continuously.

I wrote some code that didn't compile and have written over 15 codes, yet no solution. I'm kind of stuck. What am I doing wrong? I need help.

```
using System;

namespace contact
{
    public class Contact
    {
        private string fullName;
        private string phoneNumber;

        public string getName()
        {
                return fullName;
        }

        public void setName(string fullname)
        {
                this.fullName = fullname;
        }

        public string getPhonenumber()
        {
                return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
        {
                this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

    }

    public class ContactManager
    {
            public static void Main()
            {
               List<Contact> myContact() = new List<Contact>();

          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Whats the compilation error?

Answer (score 2):

Use a code like this -

```
namespace contact
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public string FullName {get; set;};
        public string PhoneNumber {get; set;};
    }

    public class ContactManager
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
           List<Contact> myContacts = new List<Contact>();
        }
    }
}
```

1. You dont have to add `()` to myContacts variable. Because you add `()` only after method names, not variable names.
2. You dont need separate get and set methods like java. You can do that using [Properties in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Just providing get and set as shown above will do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see only one possible error that can prevent your code from being compiled:

```
List<Contact> myContact() = new List<Contact>();
```

It should not be brackets here, since brackets are not allowed in variable names:

```
List<Contact> myContact = new List<Contact>();
```